# What is the general format of keyname for key bindings in "inputrc" file?

Tags: bash, readline

I understand that the format for key bindings in `inputrc` file is:

```
keyname: function-name or macro
```

For keyname, I saw things like:

```
"\e[B"
"\e[1~"
"\e[5D"
"\M-l"
"\C-[OD"
"\e\e[D"
```

What is the meaning of these keynames, and what is the general format for keyname ? Please share a link to docs.

Comment: For your docs, I'd recommend looking at the `readline(3)` manpage or the [readline user manual](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html).

Comment: Check you key configuration (readline - inputrc) via: $ bind -p

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Keybinding can be done using one of the following forms:

1. **keyname: command_name**
2. **"keystroke_sequence": command_name**

In first form you can spell out the name for a single key. For example, CONTROL-U would be written as control-u. This is useful for binding commands to single keys.

In the second form, you specify a string that describes a sequence of keys that will be bound to the command. The one you gave as an example is the emacs-tyle backslash escape sequences to represent the special keys

> `\C` - Control
>       `\M` - Meta
>       `\e` - Escape

You can specify a backslash using another backslash – `\\`.
Similarly `'` and `"` can be escaped too - `\'` and `\"`

**Update**

These characters is what is interpreted by your terminal when you press special keys. You don't want to bind regular alphabets and numerics in your key binding as you might be using them on regular basis and can cause issues when you accidentally hit a combination that has been mapped in your `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` file.

```
[1~ is what is interpreted by your terminal when you press your HOME button.
```

To learn more, simply type `read` on your terminal prompt and press all types of special keys like Function Keys, HOME, END, Arrow Keys etc and see what gets displayed.

Here is a small [reference](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/Keybindings#About_key_binding_profiles) I found that can offer some basic understanding. Good luck! :)

Comment: What does `\e[1~`, `\M-l` and `\C-[OD` mean? The `\e`, `\M`, and `\C` parts are clear. How about the rest? For example: `[1~` - Should I press `Shift`+`{`+`1`+`Shift`+`\``?

Comment: I have updated the answer for you. Hope that helps!

Comment: The link is broken. Still don't know what the tilde or open bracket are for??